# Side scrolling generic cards

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

I'd like to create the same as follow for a messenger bot but didn't find anything apart of generic cards that display only one card.

[image]

Comment: My guess, that's probably done using webviews, with is a beta feature. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic template allows you to display up to 10 elements that scroll horizontally exactly like the example you have included.

If you look at the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/generic-template) you will see that the attachment payload allows you to include an array of elements and below that "elements is limited to 10"

I can confirm it works as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your help :-)